# Seach and categories not working when ignoring sticky posts in main loop

Tags: wp-query, functions, query-posts, sticky-post

My search does not work anymore, the same goes for my categories. It now shows literally all the posts until the page limit is reached, instead of the specified ones. This happened after I made sure that the sticky posts I show on top of my page are not repeated in the main loop.

I added this to my functions.php

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'theme_ignore_sticky');
function theme_ignore_sticky($query)
{
    if (is_home() && $query->is_main_query())
        $query->set('ignore_sticky_posts', true);
}
```

and put this before my main loop in in the index.php

```
query_posts( array( 'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ), 'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) );
```

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but I highly recommend using `get_posts` instead of `query_posts`. Check [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) for reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues in your code.

First, you pass what could be a string into `post__not_in`, which accepts an array of posts IDs (that's fine if your option holds an array of IDs, but always good to verify).

Second, you seem to be repeating the same thing twice: you modify the query with `pre_get_posts` hook, and then you do it again by passing something into `query_posts`. In the documentation ([this page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/#more-information), the `posts_per_page` part), they demonstrate the two techniques as *alternatives* of doing the same thing.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I have figured it out now.